# Driod X sending attachment email issue

Tags: android, email

i have issue with Droid X phone for sending attached email from my Application.My Code working good for All other Android devices Like HTC,Samsung galaxy,Milestone. But i have problem with Droid X only.I saved my html file in the sdcard but i can not attached it in the email. i recived the empty mail, i didnt get the attachement in the droid x mobile.
here i attached my code...

save file in the sdcard:

```
protected void savehtml(HtmlViwer htmlViwer, String htmlcontent2,String string) {
    try {
       File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"PalmAgent");
        if (!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }
        String sdcardhtmlpath = root.getPath().toString() + "/print.html";
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(sdcardhtmlpath);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

        out.write(htmlcontent2);
        out.close();
      } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any

        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

sending mail with attachment:

```
  Intent sentinIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    sentinIntent.setType("plain/text");
    ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();

    File root = new ile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PalmAgent");
    String sdcardhtmlpath = root.getPath().toString()+ "/print.html";
    String[] filePaths = new String[] { sdcardhtmlpath };

      for (String file : filePaths) {
          File fileIn = new File(file);
          Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
          uris.add(u);
    }
      sentinIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sentinIntent,"Send mail via"));
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution...   while connecting to the PC the sdcard share its memory with PC so that I cannot access the sdcard that time. And also same device comes without memory card

```
Intent sentinIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sentinIntent.setType("plain/text");


File root = new ile(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Path");
String sdcardhtmlpath = root.getPath().toString()+ "/print.html";
String[] filePaths = new String[] { sdcardhtmlpath };

  uris = getURI(filePaths );
  sentinIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
  startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sentinIntent,"Send mail via"));
}
```